# Numpy: Efficient way to convert indices of a square matrix to its upper triangular indices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Question: given a tuple of index, return its order in upper triangular indices. Here is an example:

Suppose we have a square matrix A of shape (3, 3).

A has 6 upper triangular indices, namely, (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2).

Now I know an element at index (1, 2), which is a index belongs to the upper triangular part of A. I would like to return 4 (which means it is the 5th element in all upper triangular indices.)

Any ideas on how to do that in general?

Best,
Zhihao

Comment: More general, if I have a list of indices, do we have a function to convert them to triu indices together [return a list/array of converted results]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can write down the explicit formula:

```
def utr_idx(N, i, j):
    return (2*N+1-i)*i//2 + j-i
```

Demo:

```
>>> N = 127
>>> X = np.transpose(np.triu_indices(N))
>>> utr_idx(N, *X[2123])
2123
```

Comment: I just realized it lol

Comment: what about the inverse? from a vector back to matrix (i,j) indices?

Comment: Willem Van Onsem has written down the inverse in his answer @makis.

Answer (score 4):

For an *n×n* matrix, the *(i, j)*-th item of the upper triangle is the *i×(2×n-i+1)/2+j-i*-th element of the matrix.

We can also do the math in reverse and obtain the *(i, j)* element for the *k*-th element with:

*i = ⌊(-√((2n+1)<sup>2</sup>-8k)+2n+1)/2⌋* and *j = k+i-i×(2×n-i+1)/2*

So for example:

```
from math import floor, sqrt

def coor_to_idx(n, i, j):
    return i*(2*n-i+1)//2+j-i

def idx_to_coor(n, k):
    i = floor((-sqrt((2*n+1)*(2*n+1)-8*k)+2*n+1)/2)
    j = k + i - i*(2*n-i+1)//2
    return i, j
```

For example:

```
>>> [idx_to_coor(4, i) for i in range(10)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
>>> [coor_to_idx(4, i, j) for i in range(4) for j in range(i, 4)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Given the numbers are not huge (well if these are huge, calculations are no longer done in constant time), we can thus calculate the *k*-th coordinate in *O(1)*, for example:

```
>>> idx_to_coor(1234567, 123456789)
(100, 5139)
```

which is equivalent to obtaining it through enumeration:

```
>>> next(islice(((i, j) for i in range(1234567) for j in range(i, 1234567)), 123456789, None))
(100, 5139)
```

Here converting indices to a coordinate can also have, for large numbers, some rounding errors due to floating point imprecision.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can get the indexes using `itertools` combinations [with replacement](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)

```
>>> ind = tuple(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(3),2))
((0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2))
```

To retrieve the index, just use [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method

```
>>> ind.index((1,2))
4
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [np.triu_indices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html#numpy.triu_indices) and a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
import numpy as np

iu1 = np.triu_indices(3)
table = {(i, j): c for c, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(*iu1))}
print(table[(1, 2)])
```

**Output**

```
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @DanielMesejo, you can use `np.triu_indices` with either `argwhere` or `nonzero`:

```
my_index = (1,2)

>>> np.nonzero((np.stack(np.triu_indices(3), axis=1) == my_index).all(1))
(array([4]),)
>>> np.argwhere((np.stack(np.triu_indices(3), axis=1) == my_index).all(1))
array([[4]])
```

Explanation:

`np.stack(np.triu_indices(3), axis=1)` gives you the indices of your upper triangle in order:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 2]])
```

So all you have to do is find where it matches `[1,2]` (which you can do with the `==` operator and `all`)

Answer (score 1):

Constructing upper indices would be costly. We can directly get the corresponding index like so -

```
def triu_index(N, x, y):
    # Get index corresponding to (x,y) in upper triangular list
    idx = np.r_[0,np.arange(N,1,-1).cumsum()]
    return idx[x]+y-x
```

Sample run -

```
In [271]: triu_index(N=3, x=1, y=2)
Out[271]: 4
```